# Running Spark Batch tasks based on input from a Spark Stream

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have the next architecture: my web app pushes JSON messages to Kafka topics. A message represents a DSL command (kind of truncated SQL). I have a Spark task for running a single DSL command - it reads a command from JSON, it reads data from a parquet file, applies aggregations based on a command and writes a result to parquet file. I want to use Spark Streaming for listening to a Kafka topic and running batch tasks on the same cluster.
But I have a few concerns:

- Is it a good idea to use Spark Streaming for launching batch tasks on the same cluster (at least I'm concerned with tracking failed tasks)?
- I realise advantages of this architecture over running Spark cluster for batch tasks without Spark Streaming - less latency, but not sure about pitfalls like fault tolerance etc.

Comment: I'm afraid that _"I want to use Spark Streaming for listening to a Kafka topic and running batch tasks on the same cluster"_ is not possible in Spark Structured Streaming.

Comment: As for as I know, you can only use a Kafka consumer application to trigger your spark batch applications and achieve the flow you have.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski as I understood your correctly it's impossible to run a spark batch task from spark streaming (kind of using the shared cluster for both streaming and batch operations), am I right?

Comment: I think it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/58996885/1305344 where I said "this **could** work" :) I think I'm convinced to give this a shot.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski how can I track failed tasks with this approach?

Comment: @pacman Can you ask a separate question so we won't get "swamped" with the (un)pleasant comment section interface? :)