# How to execute dynamic SQLs in streaming queries?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark Structured streaming, and processing messages from Kafka.
At one point my result table looks something like below, where each line in the dataset has a Spark SQL query.

```
+----+--------------------+
|code|          triggerSql|
+----+--------------------+
|  US|SELECT * FROM def...|
|  UK|SELECT * FROM def...|
+----+--------------------+
```

I need to execute each of these queries and process the results. However, structured streaming won't allow to collect these SQLs to driver side, and We can't open a new SparkSession inside any transformation.

```
val query = df3.writeStream.foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row] {
      override def open(partitionId: Long, epochId: Long): Boolean = {
        //..
      }

      override def process(value: Row): Unit = {
        val triggerSqlString = value.getAs[String]("triggerSql")
        val code = value.getAs[String]("value")
        println("Code="+code+"; TriggerSQL="+triggerSqlString)

        //TODO

      }

      override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
       // println("===> Closing..")
      }
    }).trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 seconds"))
      .start()
```

Is there any better alternative way to dynamically execute these SQL in spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use [DataStreamWriter.foreachBatch](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch) operation.

---

The following sample shows how one could achieve execution of SQL queries from a batch dataset:

```
def sqlExecution(ds: Dataset[String], batchId: Long): Unit = {
  ds.as[String].collect.foreach { s => sql(s).show }
}
spark
  .readStream
  .textFile("sqls")
  .writeStream
  .foreachBatch(sqlExecution)
  .start
```